# i couldn't undestand what this lines of code do?

Tags: python, scipy

This part of class i did not understand what does do in this code:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if(os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,file)) and select in file): 
        temp = scipy.io.loadmat(os.path.join(path,file))
        temp = {k:v for k, v in temp.items() if k[0] != '_'}
        for i  in range(len(temp[patch_type+"_patches"])):
            self.tensors.append(temp[patch_type+"_patches"][i])
            self.labels.append(temp[patch_type+"_labels"][0][i])

self.tensors = np.array(self.tensors)
self.labels = np.array(self.labels)
```

especially this line :

```
temp = {k:v for k, v in temp.items() if k[0] != '_'}
```

**the whole class is as follow :**

```
class Datasets(Dataset):
    def __init__(self,path,train,transform=None):
        if(train):
            select ="Training"
            patch_type = "train"
        else:
            select = "Testing"
            patch_type = "testing"

        self.tensors = []
        self.labels = []
        self.transform = transform


        for file in os.listdir(path):
            if(os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,file)) and select in file): 

                temp = scipy.io.loadmat(os.path.join(path,file))
                temp = {k:v for k, v in temp.items() if k[0] != '_'}
                for i  in range(len(temp[patch_type+"_patches"])):
                    self.tensors.append(temp[patch_type+"_patches"][i])
                    self.labels.append(temp[patch_type+"_labels"][0][i])

        self.tensors = np.array(self.tensors)
        self.labels = np.array(self.labels)

    def __len__(self):
        try:
            if len(self.tensors) != len(self.labels):
                raise Exception("Lengths of the tensor and labels list are not the same")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e.args[0])
        return len(self.tensors)

    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        sample = (self.tensors[idx],self.labels[idx])
       # print(self.labels)
        sample = (torch.from_numpy(self.tensors[idx]),torch.from_numpy(np.array(self.labels[idx])).long())
        return sample
    #tuple containing the image patch and its corresponding label
```

Comment: where did you get this code? can you give me a link? also which line? or is it the part that its checking to see if a file exists?

Comment: At first glance, it appears to be cloning a dictionary minus the underscore prefixed keys.

Comment: i couldnt find the repository from github but here is the whole class :

Answer (score 2):

It's a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/); in this particular case, it creates a new `dict` from an existing dict `temp`, but only for items for which the key `k` does not start with an underscore. That check is performed by the `if ...` part.

It is equivalent to

```
new = {}
for k, v in temp.items():
    if key[0] != '_':
        new[k] = value
temp = new
```

or, slightly different:

```
new = {}
for key, value in temp.items():
    if not key.startswith('_'):
        new[key] = value
temp = new
```

You can see that it looks a bit nicer as a single line, since it avoids a temporary dict (`new`; under the hood, it still creates a nameless temporary dict though).

Answer (score 0):

It is filtering out the underscore-prefixed variables from the loaded MATLAB file. From the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html) the function `scipy.io.loadmat` returns a dictionary containing the variable names from the loaded file as keys and the matricies as values. The line of code you reference is a [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) that clones the dictionary minus the variables that fail the conditional check.

### Update

What happens here is roughly this:

1. Load a MATLAB file (`file` in your code) as a hashmap (dictionary) where the keys are the variable names from the file and the values are the matricies, assign to `temp`.
2. Iterate through those key/value pairs and drop the underscore-prefixed ones and reassign the results of *that* iteration to `temp`.
3. Profit

Comment: if i got you, the filename which starts with '_' is gonna be ignored to be assigned to temp ?

Comment: @Daniel no it has nothing to do with the filename which is denoted by the variable `file` in the code you posted. I'll update my answer.